# why reverse modulus operation give same divider value?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

modulus operator % used to find value like

$12$%$2 = 0 \qquad(12 \bmod 2 = 0)$

$10$%$3=1 \qquad(10 \bmod 3 = 1)$

this is Maximum value modulus for minimum value . Right!
but when do modulus like:

$3$%$12= \mathbf 3 \qquad(3 \bmod 12 = 3)$

$5$%$10 = \mathbf 5 \qquad(5 \bmod 10 = 5)$

But why this happen same where same value come from as divider?

Comment: Whenever $a<n$, the remainder of $a$ on division by $n$ is $a$. So $a$%$n =a$

Comment: this can consider as divide result must be < 0 like: ** 2 / 3 = 0.something ** not able to do a MOD Right ??

Comment: You "do a mod", but since the number is smaller there is nothing to remove from the original number. Like in saying $83$%$10 = 3$, I have subtracted off $8$ $10$s, but $3$%$10 = 3$ because there are no multiples of $10$ to remove.

Comment: Operator algebras ? :D

Comment: @Epsilon: I've removed the "operator algebras" and "operator theory" tags of many many  many completely unrelated questions. I guess reading the tag description is too hard.

Answer (score 1):

For $(12 \bmod 2 = 0)$ Since 12=6*2 then it is divisible by 2, which means the remainder upon dividing by 2 is 0.

For $(10 \bmod 3 = 1)$  Dividing 10 by 3 gives you as a remainder since 10 can be written as $10=3*3 +1$

For $(3 \bmod 12 = 3)$ Dividing 3 by 12 gives you a remainder of 3 since this can be written as $(0*12)+3$. This is because 0 is a multiple of 12 since 12*0 is 12*n for some integer n.

For $(5 \bmod 10 = 5)$ This is just a modified version of the previous one. Dividing 5 by 10 gives you a remainder of 5 since it can be written as $(0*10)+5$. This is once again because 0 is a multiple of 10 since 10*0 is 10*n for some integer n.

In general, one can write  $(a \bmod n)$ as $a=q*n +r$ Where q is an integer, n is the modulus, and r is an (usually positive) integer $\ge0$.